# Docker java.lang.RuntimeException when attempting to build error

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and trying to use it for one of my PHP projects on a Mac with Netbeans.

My docker file is below.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER "Joe" <joe@fakewebsitefornow.com>
# Install apache, PHP, and supplimentary programs. openssh-server, curl, and lynx-cur are for debugging the container.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
    apache2 php7.0 php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php7.0 curl lynx-cur

# Enable apache mods.
RUN a2enmod php7.0
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Update the PHP.ini file, enable <? ?> tags and quieten logging.
RUN sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*$/error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE/" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

# Manually set up the apache environment variables
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

# Expose apache.
EXPOSE 80

# Copy this repo into place.
ADD www /var/www/site

# Update the default apache site with the config we created.
ADD apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# By default start up apache in the foreground, override with /bin/bash for interative.
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

I'm using netbeans 8.2 and building my Dockerfile from there.  I setup my directory like this.

```
MyWebsite
-- www
-- Dockerfile
-- apache-config.conf
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to build.

**java.lang.RuntimeException: file name 'www/templates/vendor/symfony/console/Tests/Fixtures/application_renderexception_doublewidth1decorated.txt' is too long ( > 100 bytes)**

Before the error is a lot of statements looking like this..

```
Sending file Dockerfile
Sending file .DS_Store
Sending file apache-config.conf
Sending file .git/index
Sending file .git/FETCH_HEAD
Sending file .git/config
Sending file .git/HEAD
Sending file www/index.php
Sending file www/compileless.sh
Sending file www/configlocal.php
Sending file www/configdev.php... (shortened for brevity)
```

Not sure if its supposed to be sending my website like this?

I'm assuming something to do with filename rules between linux and mac? Problem is I can't change the filename easily since its a vendor that was downloaded via composer!

Any help is appreciated to help me build this image I'm at a loss for what to do.

If you want to simulate my dependencies here is my composer.json below.

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "components/jquery": "*",
        "components/normalize.css": "*",
        "robloach/component-installer": "*",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"app\\":"app","entities\\":"entities"},
        "files": ["lib/utilities.php","lib/security.php"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I recently got my image to build but I had to do it via console and not netbeans IDE.  I used the tricks here (https://medium.com/dev-tricks/apache-and-php-on-docker-44faef716150#.el44vofoy), in particular, docker build -t mysite .